# odom frame behaves mischievously in rviz when Configuring Robot Localization with error message TF_OLD_DATA

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ros2, rviz

I am trying to learn ros2 nav2 localization  [link](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/odom/setup_odom.html)

but when I add the ekf.yaml to launch description rviz behaves mischievously

to be specific: odom frame moves in rviz randomly and this is the error message it shows

Error message
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame base_link at time 100.100000 according to authority Authority undetectable

so according to the ros wiki page [link](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained)

I captured tf_frames and the image is attached as shown

[image]

Comment: Any chance you're using a bag file? It sounds to me like you've got two things publishing the same transform.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on a real-robot, set `use_sim_time` to `False` for each node, otherwise set it to `True`. Can you please try setting this and see if it works?

I faced an issue related to `odom frame` for my project and got this response from ROS answers which was very helpful. The explanation is wrt to my project but it should apply to anything in general.

**Important part from the link:** RViz will look at that timestamp (present in the message), then ask the transform tree where the sensor was located at that time, then render the sensor message at that position based in the fixed frame you are currently in.

So, I think that the sensor message's time and tf_tree timings are not matching.

[Can't visualize in rviz2 with 'odom' as 'Fixed Frame'](https://answers.ros.org/question/404225/cant-visualize-in-rviz2-with-odom-as-fixed-frame/)